How to Negotiate authentication with gMSA account in ASP.NET Core app running on Kestrel
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that runs as a Windows service under gMSA (group Managed Service Account) in test on-prem AD environment using a Kestrel web server.
App uses Negotiate authentication (without fallback policy):
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();  
...  
app.UseAuthentication();  
app.UseAuthorization();

I also have this route:
app.MapGet("/",
        [Authorize](HttpContext context) =>
        {
            var identity = context.User.Identity;
            if (identity is null)            
                return Results.Ok("user is null");            

            var username = identity.Name;
            if (username is null)            
                return Results.Ok("username is null");

            return Results.Ok
            (new { Username = identity.Name.Split('\\')[1] }); });

Now when I start the service and send a GET request:
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://server.domain.net' -UseDefaultCredentials -Verbose

When request sent from the same server where the application is running, I get following response
VERBOSE: Requested HTTP/1.1 GET with 0-byte payload
VERBOSE: Received HTTP/1.1 response of content type application/json of unknown size
VERBOSE: Content encoding: utf-8

username
--------
User

Now when I send the request from any other machine (using the same user) in the domain, I got the following:
VERBOSE: Requested HTTP/1.1 GET with 0-byte payload
VERBOSE: Received HTTP/1.1 0-byte response of content type
Invoke-RestMethod: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Note: firewall disabled on all machines for testing purposes, SPN is set correctly (at least I followed Microsoft support article)
What can be the cause of this behavior?

Hi ispa, please try to enable asp.net core loging feature and share the detailed logs, then we can check the authentication issue.

I figured it out:
I created gMSA account incorrectly
New-ADServiceAccount -Name 'service-gMSA' -DNSHostname 'server.domain.net'

I gave to gMSA account DNSHostname equal to FQDN of the server that runs service under gMSA account.
So the correct command would be:
New-ADServiceAccount -Name 'service-gMSA' -DNSHostname 'service-gMSA.domain.net'

